Defragmentation tools for Linux and/or bootable USBs
I've been looking for a defragmentation tool I can run from outside of Windows. Running within Linux would be preferable, but I will also take a bootable thing (bootable USB/CD/DVD) if that's what there is. Must be free — no paid tools.
Does anyone know of anything like this? I cannot find any such tool for the life of me. Everything I can find requires Windows, and I'd rather not have to boot into a live Windows image just to run a defrag tool. I only really need to defragment FAT/exFAT and NTFS filesystems, so it's okay if the tool is constrained to those.
Warning: this is not an XY problem! I'm not looking for alternatives to defragmentation, or reasons why it's not necessary. I'm aware of this. I'm looking for a defragmentation tool because I need a partition defragmented, not because I'm looking for an explanation on why not to do it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community I can only assume this is some sort of AI-based detection gone wrong? The question is pretty clear.

@aaaaaa123456789 - You are asking for a software recommendation. Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope. This absolutely is not “AI”, multiple humans, voted to close your question

Try on Software Recommendations site
